# I need to move 1000 files in to 1000 different folders

Tags: command-line

I have 1000 files grouped in a single directory. And I need to store each file in their own directory.

I'm looking for a solution to create 1000 directories with the same naming as the files and also move the files in to their own directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1016517/how-to-move-files-into-corresponding-folders-which-have-the-same-name

Answer (score 2):

I am happy to tell you that this is a relatively simple thing to accomplish:

```
for f in *.* ; do (mkdir -p new/$f && cp $f new/$f/ ) ; done
```

This will place a folder with the same name as the file in the "new" folder location and copy the file in question there. If they are large files and this would take some time, I suggest you include an "echo" statement in the one-liner to show where you are at.